# Route all packets on port 80 from inside a vm to a kali linux on another vm

Tags: linux, routes, port, virtualbox, iptables

I'm trying to route all packets on port 80 to kali linux so that I can ssl strip them but I cannot seem to setup the iptables correctly to force all the packets to go to my other VM.

[ Virtual Machine #1] ---------------------------- > [ Virtual Machine #2 ] route all packets on port 80

Information - I'm using vbox both VM's are using NAT
10.0.2.15 was the inet addr of my kali linux but idk what happened they now both have the same ip addr. I think i screwed something up while messing with it

Things I've Tried:

```
sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1 #to enable port forwarding

iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.2.15:80
```

`10.0.2.15` is the inet addr of my kali.

My VM network configurations #1 (The one that needs to route all of its packets to other one):

```
eth0 Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr 08:00:27:a7:ff:7a
inet addr:10.0.2.15 Bcast:10.0.2.255 Mask:255.255.255.0 inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fea7:ff7a/64 Scope:Link UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST MTU:1500 Metric:1 RX packets:13651 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0 TX packets:3711 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0 collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 RX bytes:17769462 (16.9 MiB) TX bytes:262897 (256.7 KiB)

lo Link encap:Local Loopback
inet addr:127.0.0.1 Mask:255.0.0.0 inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host UP LOOPBACK RUNNING MTU:65536 Metric:1 RX packets:234701 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0 TX packets:234701 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0 collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 RX bytes:33563198 (32.0 MiB) TX bytes:33563198 (32.0 MiB)
```

My VM network configurations #2 (The one that is taking all the routed packets):

```
eth10 Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr 08:00:27:65:07:56
inet addr:10.0.2.15 Bcast:10.0.2.255 Mask:255.255.255.0 inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe65:756/64 Scope:Link UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST MTU:1500 Metric:1 RX packets:4403 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0 TX packets:2514 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0 collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 RX bytes:4828213 (4.8 MB) TX bytes:315305 (315.3 KB)

lo Link encap:Local Loopback
inet addr:127.0.0.1 Mask:255.0.0.0 inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host UP LOOPBACK RUNNING MTU:16436 Metric:1 RX packets:23 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0 TX packets:23 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0 collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 RX bytes:1913 (1.9 KB) TX bytes:1913 (1.9 KB)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the IP address of both VMs is identical. Both `eth0` of `VM1` and `eth10` of `VM2` are `10.0.2.15`. Please change one of them and set the `--to-destination` field of the `iptables` command to `eth10`'s IP address.

Comment: I noticed noticed that. I believe I accidentally modified the ip somehow when messing with the ip tables. I know i can change it with ifconfig eht0 newIp mask but isn't there something else I need to fix inorder for it to have internet access again?

Comment: Well, your original question doesn't mention your internet access setup, so I'm unsure whether anything else should be modified. Just try modifying `VM1`'s IP address and see if you have internet access and whether packets are forwarded as required. If internet access isn't available, please verify that the VM software configuration itself lets traffic pass through in and out of the defined VMs and that it isn't blocked by an external firewall. Also, please post the output of the command `route -n` for both VMs and for the host PC as well.